# Why does Android MediaPlayer play only once if I do not declare it inside loop?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, android-mediaplayer

I have a loop, that gets an incomming stream, writes it to a temp file, and on each loop it sets the android MediaPlayer setdatasource to that file. If I declare it inside the loop, it will play, but if it is outside of the loop, it will only play once?

```
Java.IO.File temp = Java.IO.File.CreateTempFile("temp", "mp3");
Java.IO.FileInputStream fis = new Java.IO.FileInputStream(temp);
temp.DeleteOnExit();

MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

while (true)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[10000];
        Java.IO.FileOutputStream fos = new Java.IO.FileOutputStream(temp);

        mmInStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
        fos.Write(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
        player.SetDataSource(fis.FD);
        player.Prepare();
        player.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            if (!player.IsPlaying)
            {
                player.Reset();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Input stream was disconnected", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not doing any cleanup after each use - try calling Release() and Reset() before reusing it

Comment: I did try to release the player after it ends playing/tried to reset to in the 2 while loop

Answer (score 0):

You can either implement IDisposable that you can see [here](https://github.com/ImDaeseong/VocaKnowSource/blob/f2e89603d602daabc2fa916fb2be3f9003772637/VocaKnow/VocaKnow/VocaKnow/VocaKnow.Android/Mp3Player.cs), that will remove the messy while loops. Or preferably you can simply just make use of the Completion event handler that you already have access to, as you can see [here](https://github.com/timurmug/Interval-Training/blob/abaf91e0c4224da3eb9ff5722f2a86017bcafd93/Interval%20Training/Interval%20Training.Android/AudioDroid%20.cs):

```
player.Completion += (s, e) =>
{ 
    // Do work
}
```

Also, try be more clear next time, since you have two loops, and you didn't mention which loop you were talking about

Comment: Tried this, but if I recreate MediaPlayer in each loop, it will skip parts of music, but if I place it outside the first loop, it will only play one time

Comment: Does the behaviour change based on android version or device manufacturer? Also is it the same behaviour on emulator and actual device?

Comment: It does not change, same on emulated and acctual

Comment: Did you check out the examples I shared? You can also just do a search on all github open repos, for “ new MediaPlayer();” in C# code